# Regex for replacing the number by 2* the number -1. Used for replacing file names

Tags: regex, digit

I need the regular expression for multiplying the digits in the filename by 2 and subtracting 1. 
 for eg: filename12.pdf should become filename23.pdf
filename225.pdf should become filename449.pdf

Please help me with the regular expression.

Comment: regex might vary with the language...

Comment: Any particular language you are using?

Comment: Enggr, as DhruvPathak mentioned, your have not 'accepted' an official answer for *any* of your questions, except 'XSL for converting all rows and columns of XSL for Export to Excel. dynamic looping.' Please revisit some of your older questions and select your favorite answers. This will give others an incentive to answer your questions. Finally, please specify the programming language for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

A regex generally cannot do calculations, but it can help you capture the number. You can use a callback of replace. Here's C#, for example:

Helper method (we could have used a lambda, but it's less pretty):

```
public string CalculateNumber(Match match)
{
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value);
    i = i * 2 - 1;
    return i.ToString();
}
```

Regex replace:

```
String fileName = "filename23.pdf";
fileName = Regex.Replace(fileName, @"\d+", CalculateNumber);
```

An important note here is that the string may represent a too large integer (so it won't parse).  Also, `i*2-1` may overflow, resulting in a negative number. You may use a [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) block, or use a [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (with .Net 4).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $in = 'filename225.pdf';
$in =~ s/(\d+)/$1*2-1/e;
say $in;
```

**output:**

```
filename449.pdf
```

or in php :

```
function compute($matches) {
    return $matches[1]*2-1;
}
$in = 'filename225.pdf';
$res = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+)/',"compute", $in);;
echo $res,"\n";
```