# Rename files based on arithmetic rules gained from another directory in perl on windows

Tags: regex, perl, digit

So I need to loop through some files in an array, and increase the number contained in the line by the number of "*)_Graph_S1.dat" files in the directory below. I next need to rename the file to with the replaced number so that `plate0013 (44)_Graph_S1.dat` would become `plate0013 (88)_Graph_S1.dat` if there were 44 files in the below directory. For example, I'm working in the directory: `plate0013\2nd run\`. I need to rename the files in the directory `\2nd run\` based on the number of "*)_Graph_S1.dat" files in the `plate0013` directory.

I'm using windows 7 and strawberry perl.

I have tried the code located here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5029064/2060081,
but my output is not changed.

I haven't figured out how to get a count of the files in the previous directory, so I have used the filler `44` until I'm no longer stuck. Here are the important parts of my code:

```
my @array = glob('*)_Graph_S1.dat');

foreach (@array) {
    my $in = $_;
    $in =~ s/(\d+)\)/$1+44/e;
    rename $_, %in;
}
```

**My problem is that I need to include the parenthetical in the new name, and I cannot figure out how to do this.**

I've never used regular expressions before, and I haven't programmed in perl since 1995. My google skills have failed me. Thank you for reading and for your replies.

So thanks to @TLP, I've figured out why my system code wasn't outputting properly. But I've discovered a problem with my Regular Expression. My files are named like `plate 0013 (01)_Graph_S1.dat`. But it does not include the parenthetical in the new name.

Comment: Define "below" in the sentence `the number of "*)_Graph_S1.dat" files in the directory below.`

Comment: @TLP Thanks! I wasn't sure about how to describe it correctly. I edited the original post to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So basically, the number you are after is the size of `@array`? Oh, and immediately delete that `system` hack. `File::Copy` or Perl's built in `rename` is what you should use.

Comment: The size of the ``@array`` of the ``plate 0013`` directory, but the files I want to rename are in the ``2nd run`` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `@array` contains files  from `2nd run`,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = glob('*)_Graph_S1.dat');

# forcing list context => perldoc -f glob
my $number_of_files_in_dir_below = @{[ glob('../*)_Graph_S1.dat') ]};

foreach (@array) {
    my $in = $_;
    $in =~ s/(\d+)\)/$1+$number_of_files_in_dir_below .")"/e;
    rename $_, $in;
}
```